# Angular2 refresh router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular-routing

I'm working on a CRM and I have a select box in the header which allows the user to change the current user,
In addition, the main content is inside the router-outlet.

When the user select another user I want to refresh the page but only the router-outlet so the info will be for the new user

I saw that other CRMs just redirect the user to the dashboard / index page,
but I want to keep the user on the same page.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you update the model, bindings will be updated. There shouldn't be any need to refresh a router-outlet.

Comment: when the user choose an option from the selectbox a call is being made for the api and just update the user information that stored in the session storage, and when for example you are clicking on 'settings' page, the component that shows in the router-outlet is making a call to the API and send the user id from the session storage, so I need to recall the API to get this data again but for the right user, this is why I want to refresh the page so the call will happened again with the right user id

Comment: I'd create a `LoginStatusService` or similar with an observable that emits a value on login status change and the component should subscribe to that observable and make the API call if it receives a value.

Answer (score 3):

> You should have a function in a service

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

onUserChange= new Subject<void>();

userChange(): void {
    this.http.post('')
        .map()
        .subscribe((data: UserChangeResponse) => {
             this.onUserChange.next();
        })
}
```

> And In component you can use it in ngOnInit

```
serviceReference.onUserChange.subscribe(() => {

     // use can call get users method or anything

});
```

Comment: I'd use a `BehaviorSubject` with an initial value.