# Angular2 Change Detection

Tags: javascript, angular

I was learning about the how angular2 change detection works. I got the point that by default angular2 changeDetection works from the root node. After reading more about this I got the point that angular generate VM friendly code and perform more than thousand of checks within seconds for applying the change detection on the component.

Can anyone please let me know more details about how angular generate VM friendly code practically using one code example?

Comment: Might this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406679/angular2-refresh-router-outlet/44407722#44407722